# Downloading all property values?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

Is there a way to download all property values ?

For example, the Beatles have a dbpedia-owl:hometown proptery that points to http://dbpedia.org/ontology/hometown  . Is there a way to get property/values for all the properties of all instances ? To be clear, I want the property/values of the properties !!

```
Property    Value
----------------------------------
rdf:type    owl:ObjectProperty
rdfs:domain dbpedia-owl:Person
rdfs:label  home town
rdfs:range  dbpedia-owl:Settlement
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean?  There is a property dbpedia-owl:hometown, and it's got the values that you mentioned in the question.  E.g., it's an object property, its domain and range are Person and Settlement, and its label is "home town".  Do you want the preperties about a property, or something else?

Comment: Also, I've added some more tags to the question.  You've only had 7 views in 2 days, which is pretty low by Stack Overflow standards.  A few more relevant tags will help in the future.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I mean, is there a way to download a zip file of all the property/values of all instances.  I couldnt find anything on the dbpedia site that mentioned a way to get this. I wanted to examine just the properties/values of all the instances.

Comment: **"all the property/values of all instances"** All data in RDF is triples of the form [subject property value], so it sounds like you just want *all the data*.  If you go to http://dbpedia.org/, there's a **Downloads** link on the left hand column, and you can find links for all the DBpedia data.  It's broken down into different bits, though.  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Joshua, I know that RDF is in Triples and where you can download everything from. For each instance (eg: The Beatles, Michael Jordan) there are  [subject property value] , but the properties also have  [subject property value] of the properties. Thats what I'm trying to download. So "hometown" would be one example as I mentioned above

Comment: I still don't understand what it is exactly that you want.  Providing a simple example would help a lot.  A simple construct query like `construct where { dbpedia-owl:hometown ?p ?o }` will give you all the triples where dbpedia-owl:hometown in the subject.  You can easily modify that to describe all the properties.  However, there are *lots* of properties, and you'll be getting *lots* of data.

Comment: In addition to that, you might to well to restrict your attention to some subset of the properties, e.g., the dbpedia ontology (i.e., dbpedia-owl:...) properties.